# Netbeans and "Please install Android target 17 (the Android newest SDK)" on linux

Tags: android, netbeans, cordova

I've installed android sdk, added it to path, etc. but when I click on "run" in netbeans with chosen "Android Device" output always ends up like that:

> Please install Android target 17 (the Android newest SDK). Make sure
>   you have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run "android"
>   from your command-line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.

When I'm trying from console "phonegap run android" in the same project then it correctly installs on my phone.

Something wrong with netbeans configuration? I can't figure how to repeair it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message. Run 'android' from the command-line, a window will popup showing all the SDK packages. Install the Android 4.2.2 (API 17) SDK Platform. 
After installing the SDK Platform, try rebuilding in Netbeans and it should build to device.

UPDATE: 
According to the comments, Netbeans used a different SDK than the 'android' command. By using the same SDK, the issue was fixed.

Comment: well I forgot to say that but I've added api 17, 19 and also 14.

Comment: Did you follow these steps: http://forums.netbeans.org/post-151652.html

I guess Netbeans uses another SDK, probably in the Netbeans folder. Can you check if Netbeans points to the same SDK as the SDK which the 'android' command uses?

Comment: i didn't follow those steps. I've installed netbeans 7.4, just added plugin and installed everything what was needed. Also I've added path variables. It worked on windows. How to check to which SDK points netbeans and to which "android" command?

Comment: In Netbeans:
19. Go to Tools->Options->Miscellaneous->Android 
There is now an android tab in your options. Set the location 
of your android SDK installation. 

The 'android' command: enter 'whereis android' in a terminal.

Comment: well, strange thing - even though "android" command runs correctly, "whereis android" shows "android:"

Comment: And 'type -a android' ?
If that doesn't work, try executing the 'android' binary used by netbeans(by locating the SDK folder). That one probably doesn't have the SDK Platform for API 17 installed.

Comment: I updated the answer, can you accept it as correct answer so this thread gets marked as 'Answered' ?